Can I optimize this cpu-bound pandas code with polars?
I have this pandas code:
def last_non_null(s):
    return s.dropna().iloc[-1] if not s.dropna().empty else np.nan

def merge_rows_of_final_df(df_final):
    # Group by columns A, B, and C
    cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    # Apply function to each column not in the subset
    # NOTE: the other columns have np.float32 as dtype
    agg_dict = {col: last_non_null for col in df_final.columns.difference(cols)}

    # Group and aggregate
    return df_final.groupby(cols).agg(agg_dict).reset_index()

df_merged = merge_rows_of_final_df(df_final)

Can I optimize this with polars? If so, can someone provide me the polars snippet with the same output? The idea is that final_df is the result of concat a list of dataframes that have duplicates on the subset columns A,B,C. I wish to merge the rows of those groups by taking the last/first not-null value of each column.
Example input:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[1,1,1,1,4,4,4],
    "B":[2,2,2,2,5,5,5],
    "C":[3,3,3,3,6,6,6],
    "D":[4, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan],
    "E":[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7, np.nan, np.nan, 2],
    "F":[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
})

Example output:
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1   2   3   4.0 7.0 NaN
1   4   5   6   1.0 2.0 NaN


Can you please provide an example df_final along with the output?

@jqurious edited the question with input and output example

You can drop_nulls() and then take the last()
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "A":[1,1,1,1,4,4,4],
    "B":[2,2,2,2,5,5,5],
    "C":[3,3,3,3,6,6,6],
    "D":[4, None, None, None, 1, None, None],
    "E":[None, None, None, 7, None, None, 2],
    "F":[None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
})

df.group_by("A", "B", "C").agg(
    pl.all().drop_nulls().last()
)

shape: (2, 6)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬──────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C   ┆ D   ┆ E   ┆ F    │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ null │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 3   ┆ 4   ┆ 7   ┆ null │
│ 4   ┆ 5   ┆ 6   ┆ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ null │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴──────┘


Thank you. The original code took 45m to finish with pandas, with polars 6s. Would you mind elaborating more on the logic so that I can compare if the same logic is applied? (the trivial provided example is okay). Maybe I can compute both outputs with pandas and polars and compare the two dataframe in-memory?

It's the same logic as your example. It groups by A,B,C and drop_nulls().last() is how you say .dropna().iloc[-1] in Polars. You don't need to do the column difference stuff as pl.all() wont include the group keys when used inside .agg()

What if one column has no not-null values?

It will produce null.

I noticed that after upgrading packages (polars is now 0.20.25) the output changed (not the given trivial example). In particular, the other columns (except the last one) have 0 non-null counts. Is it possible somehow now it is computing the logic on the last column instead of taking that last row of each group? Maybe something changed in all(), drop_nulls(), or something else?

It's difficult to say what the problem could be without a test case. There should be no changes in all / drop_nulls. You can use pl.exclude("A", "B", "C").drop_nulls().last() if you wanted to be explicit with the columns - but it should be equivalent.
